# Best way to permanently redirect lots of URLs on a typical LAMP Server

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, forwarding

I'm trying to determine the best way to forward lots of urls permanently in terms of performance and operability. So there are 3 possible ways I could image so far:

- .htaccess RewriteRule
- PHP header function looking for matching urls in an array
- PHP header function looing into a MySql Database

It's not about forwarding a whole domain but only some urls of domains. Like e.g. when product names change from *something* to *anything_else*:

```
www.example.com/something > www.example.com/anything_else
```

while URLs like *www.example.com/totally_differnt* remains untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go for sweet point between manageability and perofrmance, I suggest a two-step process (we use the same for our HTTP routing configuration):

1. URLs exist in database for easy maintainability
2. A Script (bash, PHP, whatever) creates a PHP script from the DB and a template, defining an array with the original path as the key and the new path as a value, then looking up the requested document path and if found redirecting to the new one, if not showing a 404. This "script creating script" is run, if the DB changes
3. The generated script is used as a 404 fallback

If you use HHVM or an opcode cache, this is blazingly fast: The code itself is ready, and all that needs to be done is a hashtable lookup.